# Other components doesn't follow the animated image

Tags: react-native

I have a simple animated image,that scales down when keyboards open and scales back if keyboard closes.
I did to prevent scrolling on login screen, but now other components don't follow the image.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm using react-native-easy-grid
The code:

```
export default class AnimatedImage extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }
  _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 0.5
    }).start();
  };
  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      friction: 3,
      tension: 40
    }).start();
  };

  render() {
    const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    return (
      <Animated.Image
        source={require("../../../assets/ic_splash.png")}
        resizeMode="center"
        style={{
          borderColor: "#000",
          borderWidth: 1,
          width: "100%",
          height: 200,
          transform: [{ scale: this.animatedValue }]
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm calling it here:

```
<Grid>
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<Grid>
            <Col style={{ alignItems: "center",justifyContent:"flex-start" }}>
            <AnimatedImage/>

....OTHER COMPONENTS...
</Col>
</Grid>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</Grid>
```

[image][image]
Thanks!

Comment: You can add `KeyboardAvoidingView`

Comment: Oh,I didn't copied that,sorry. Its already in,but it only pushes up the whole screen.

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: I have edited the question. I had to add another Grid because toast doesn't show inside the keyboardAvoidingView

Comment: Delete `Grid` and add `keyboardAvoidingView` to image class.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added images.The container stays the same size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I managed to do it with `LayoutAnimation` instead of `Animate.Image`.
Here is the code that works as expected:

```
export default class AnimatedImage extends Component<Props> {
  state = { keyboardState: "closed" };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }
  _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    this.setState({ keyboardState: "opened" });
  };
  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    this.setState({ keyboardState: "closed" });
  };

  render() {
    const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: this.state.keyboardState == "closed" ? 200 : 100
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: this.state.keyboardState == "closed" ? 200 : 100
          }}
          resizeMode="center"
          source={require("../../../assets/ic_splash.png")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I think its easy and simple.